# If else statement not calling isServiceCharge() method?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, method-call

I am almost finished with this bank account program. I have a call to the `calculateSavings()` method or the `calculateCheckings()` method. If the `currentBalance` is less than the required `minSavings` or `minChecking`, I have an `else` statement to call the `isServiceCharge()` method to deduct a fee. The program is not giving me errors, but if the user inputs a `currentBalance` that is less than the required amount for `minChecking` or `minSavings`, the `JOptionPane` is not showing the output. The inputs still work but there is no output popping up. Everything else works fine such as adding interest, but deducting a fee in the service charge isn't. How can I fix this?

Main class

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        {
            BankAccount myBank = new BankAccount();

            myBank.calculateNewBalance();
        }
    }
}
```

BankAccount class

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;

public class BankAccount
{
    private int accountNumber;
    private String accountType;
    private double minSavings = 2500.00;
    private double minChecking = 1000.00;
    private double currentBalance;

    public BankAccount()
    {
        accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your account number"));
        accountType = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your account type");
        currentBalance = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your current balance."));
    }

    public int getAccountNumber()
    {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber)
    {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public String getAccountType()
    {
        return accountType;
    }

    public void setAccountType(String accountType)
    {
        this.accountType = accountType;
    }

    public double getMinSavings()
    {
        return minSavings;
    }

    public void setMinSavings(double minSavings)
    {
        this.minSavings = minSavings;
    }

    public double getMinChecking()
    {
        return minChecking;
    }

    public void setMinChecking(double minChecking)
    {
        this.minChecking = minChecking;
    }

    public double getCurrentBalance()
    {
        return currentBalance;
    }

    public void setCurrentBalance(double currentBalance)
    {
        this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
    }

    public void calculateNewBalance()
    {
        if (accountType.equals("S") || accountType.equals("s"))
        {
            accountType = "Savings";
            calculateSavingsBalance();
        } else if (accountType.equals("C") || accountType.equals("c"))
        {
            accountType = "Checking";
            calculateCheckingBalance();
        }
    }

    private void calculateSavingsBalance()
    {
        if (currentBalance >= minSavings)
        {
            double newBalance = currentBalance + (currentBalance * .04 / 12);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Number: " + getAccountNumber() + "\nAccount Type: " + getAccountType() + "\nMinimum Balance: $" + getMinSavings()
                + "\nBalance Before Interest and Fees: $" + getCurrentBalance() + "\n\nNew Balance: $" + newBalance);
        }
        else if(currentBalance < minSavings)
        {
            isServiceCharge();
        }
    }

    private void calculateCheckingBalance()
    {
        if (currentBalance > 6000)
        {
            double newBalance = currentBalance + (currentBalance * .03 / 12);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Number: " + getAccountNumber() + "\nAccount Type: " + getAccountType() + "\nMinimum Balance: $" + getMinSavings()
                + "\nBalance Before Interest and Fees: $" + getCurrentBalance() + "\n\nNew Balance: $" + newBalance);
        }
        else if (currentBalance >= minChecking)
        {
            double newBalance = currentBalance + (currentBalance * .05 / 12);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Number: " + getAccountNumber() + "\nAccount Type: " + getAccountType() + "\nMinimum Balance: $" + getMinSavings()
                + "\nBalance Before Interest and Fees: $" + getCurrentBalance() + "\n\nNew Balance: $" + newBalance);
        }
        else if(currentBalance < minChecking)
        {
            isServiceCharge();
        }
    }

    public void isServiceCharge()
    {
        if(accountType.equals("s") || accountType.equals("S"))
        {
            double newBalance = currentBalance - 10.0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Number: " + getAccountNumber() + "\nAccount Type: " + getAccountType() + "\nMinimum Balance: $" + getMinSavings()
                + "\nBalance Before Interest and Fees: $" + getCurrentBalance() + "\n\nNew Balance: $" + newBalance);
        }
        else if(accountType.equals("c") || accountType.equals("C"))
        {
            double newBalance = currentBalance - 25.0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Number: " + getAccountNumber() + "\nAccount Type: " + getAccountType() + "\nMinimum Balance: $" + getMinSavings()
                + "\nBalance Before Interest and Fees: $" + getCurrentBalance() + "\n\nNew Balance: $" + newBalance);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should learn how to use a debugger...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is happening actually in your code,

```
public void calculateNewBalance()
{
    if (accountType.equals("S") || accountType.equals("s"))
    {
        accountType = "Savings";
        calculateSavingsBalance();

    } else if (accountType.equals("C") || accountType.equals("c"))
    {
        accountType = "Checking";
        calculateCheckingBalance();
    }


}
```

for ***s or S accountType = "Savings";***

for ***c or C accountType = "Checking";***

but interestingly in ***isServiceCharge()*** method

```
public void isServiceCharge()
{
    if(accountType.equals("s") || accountType.equals("S"))
    {
        double newBalance = currentBalance - 10.0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Number: " + getAccountNumber() + "\nAccount Type: " + getAccountType() + "\nMinimum Balance: $" + getMinSavings()
                + "\nBalance Before Interest and Fees: $" + getCurrentBalance() + "\n\nNew Balance: $" + newBalance);
    }
    else if(accountType.equals("c") || accountType.equals("C"))
    {
        double newBalance = currentBalance - 25.0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Number: " + getAccountNumber() + "\nAccount Type: " + getAccountType() + "\nMinimum Balance: $" + getMinSavings()
                + "\nBalance Before Interest and Fees: $" + getCurrentBalance() + "\n\nNew Balance: $" + newBalance);
    }

}
```

you checked

```
accountType.equals("s") || accountType.equals("S") //for savings
accountType.equals("C") || accountType.equals("c")// for checking
```

so above condition will never meet.

so the solution is:

```
public void isServiceCharge()
{
    if(accountType.equals("Savings"))
    {
        double newBalance = currentBalance - 10.0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Number: " + getAccountNumber() + "\nAccount Type: " + getAccountType() + "\nMinimum Balance: $" + getMinSavings()
                + "\nBalance Before Interest and Fees: $" + getCurrentBalance() + "\n\nNew Balance: $" + newBalance);
    }
    else if(accountType.equals("Checking"))
    {
        double newBalance = currentBalance - 25.0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Number: " + getAccountNumber() + "\nAccount Type: " + getAccountType() + "\nMinimum Balance: $" + getMinSavings()
                + "\nBalance Before Interest and Fees: $" + getCurrentBalance() + "\n\nNew Balance: $" + newBalance);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small issue

If you see this function you are changing the account type to **'Savings' or 'Checking'**.

```
public void calculateNewBalance()
   {
    if (accountType.equals("S") || accountType.equals("s"))
    {
        accountType = "Savings";
        calculateSavingsBalance();

    } else if (accountType.equals("C") || accountType.equals("c"))
    {
        accountType = "Checking";
        calculateCheckingBalance();
    }


}
```

Yet you are comparing accountType with **'c' or 's'** in

```
public void isServiceCharge()
{
    if(accountType.equals("s") || accountType.equals("S"))
    {
        double newBalance = currentBalance - 10.0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Number: " + getAccountNumber() + "\nAccount Type: " + getAccountType() + "\nMinimum Balance: $" + getMinSavings()
                + "\nBalance Before Interest and Fees: $" + getCurrentBalance() + "\n\nNew Balance: $" + newBalance);
    }
    else if(accountType.equals("c") || accountType.equals("C"))
    {
        double newBalance = currentBalance - 25.0;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Account Number: " + getAccountNumber() + "\nAccount Type: " + getAccountType() + "\nMinimum Balance: $" + getMinSavings()
                + "\nBalance Before Interest and Fees: $" + getCurrentBalance() + "\n\nNew Balance: $" + newBalance);
    }

}
```

That is the reason it is not entering into either of the blocks, So if you change the conditions to below statements

```
if(accountType.equals("Savings"))

else if(accountType.equals("Checking"))
```

It will work as you expected